# Where was Slater's condition first used?

Tags: reference-request, optimization, math-history, convex-optimization

I've been looking all over the internet to answer this question: *Slater's condition* is a commonly used to certify that strong duality holds in a convex optimization problem.

Although used in many papers and textbooks, I have been unable to find a reference to the paper in which this condition was first used. What are the origins of this condition? Who invented Slater's condition? Presumably this was a Mr. or Ms. Slater? Does anyone have a reference for me?

Comment: I found only three references to the condition in my books (and none of them provide a reference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

M. Slater, "Lagrange Multipliers Revisited," Cowles Commission Discussion
Paper No. 403, November, 1950

Comment: +1: Wow. How did you find that?

Comment: I have googled it :)

Comment: I'm showing my age :-).

Comment: @MohammadKhosravi: Wow, so did I, but I couldn't find any reference! Thanks very much!

Comment: @Yori: You are welcome! as I always say, we are here to help each other and also learn! :) BTW It seems that you are a graduate student!yeah?

Comment: @copper.hat Experience can never be substituted by knowledge, updates, ... . We learn from our teachers and teach our students. For sure many people have learned numerous valuable things in your classes and they owe you their own knowledge.

Comment: @Yori: So nice! I am greatly interested in optimization, and based on my research problem, I greatly use it.

Comment: @Yori It seems that you are interested in discrete math and discrete optimization! :)

Comment: I have seen what is referred to as the Slater condition many times (mostly in the context of duality & sensitivity), but often it is not named as such. It is convenient to have a personalized label for such things, but often correct (or attempts at) attribution lends to unwieldy names (example, the Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality). (Slater's condition is obviously not a good example of the latter!)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting! The fulltext of the paper is here:

https://cowles.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/pub/cdp/m-0403.pdf